# Returning True if matching value found in array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I feel like this should be easy but I've been running into problems finding a solution.

I have an array of file extensions:

```
var items = ["PDF", "XLS"]
```

I also have an array of file objects:

```
files = [{format: "TXT"},{format: "PDF"}]
```

I'd like a function where I can pass the array of file objects, and if any of the files have a format that is in the items array, it should return true.

Thank you in advance for the help.

```
function hasItemExtension() {
  files.forEach(file => {
    if(items.indexOf(file.format) != -1) {
      return true;
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you're trying to break a `forEach()` with a `return` and apparently it can't be done according to this [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by
>   throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the forEach() method
>   is the wrong tool. Use a plain loop or [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) instead....

I have worked out this little example where I set the boolean variable and modify it if there is a match:

```js
var items = ['PDF', 'XLS'];

var files = [{ format: 'PDF' }, { format: 'XLS' }];

function hasItemExtension(items, files) {
 let result = false;
 
 files.forEach(function(file){
  let f = file.format;
  if (items.indexOf(f) !== -1){
   result = true;
  }
 });
 return result;
}

let sol = hasItemExtension(items, files);

console.log(sol);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use javascript's array.some() method

```js
    var items = ["PDF", "XLS"]
    
    var files = [{format: "TXT"},{format: "PDF"}]
    
    console.log(files.some(file => items.indexOf(file.format) > -1))
```